# How to get data on x-axis and number of times occured on y-axis using crossfilter JS?

Tags: jquery, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am using crossfilter to get data on x-axis and number of times occured on y-axis.

```
     var data = [{
     Owner: "Alyssa",
    ID: "A"
    }, {
        Owner: "Alyssa",
       ID: "A"
    }, {
       Owner: "Alyssa",
       ID: "A"
  }, {
      Owner: "Alyssa",
      ID: "A"
  }, {
      Owner: "Alyssa",
      ID: "B"
     }, {
    Owner: "Bob",
    ID: "A"

}, {
    Owner: "Bob",
    ID: "D"
}, {
Owner: "Joe",
ID: "A"
}, {
   Owner: "Joe",
    ID: "A"
}, {
    Owner: "Joe",
    ID: "D"
}, {
    Owner: "Joe",
    ID: "D"

}];
var dropdown_cross1 = crossfilter(data); 
var x_owner_filter=dropdown_cross1.dimension(function (d){

        for (var key in d)
        { 
            if(d[key] == "D")
            {
                //console.log("selected_text="+selected_text);
                //console.log('key=' + key + ' value=' + d[key]); 
                console.log(d[key]);
                 return d[key];
            } 

         }

    });

   //x_owner_filter.filter("D");

    var y_owner_filter = x_owner_filter.group().reduceCount();


    var size=y_owner_filter.size();
    console.log("size="+size);

    var size_ownertitle = y_owner_filter.top(size);
    console.log(size_ownertitle);
```

**Output**

```
[Object { key="D",  value=11}]
```

**Output must be**  [Object { key="D",  value=3}]

I am new to crossfillter, do not know where is the the problem?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mukesh_tejra/rvfw4x06/1/) see output in browser's console.

**See updated** [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvfw4x06/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting to count the Ds, that would be an ID dimension, which is simply:

```
var x_id_dim = dropdown_cross1.dimension(function (d){
    return d.ID;
});
```

Now, the Y values come from the group associated with the dimension:

```
var y_id_group = x_id_dim.group().reduceCount();
```

You might also want an owner dimension, create that separately.

I suspect the confusion here might be the crossfilter definition of "dimension" - they really mean "some key you want to bin and filter on" not dimension as in X and Y. Typically the Y chart-dimension will come from the group aggregation.

Comment: Just have look updated jsfiddle link and see output in browser's console.In that you will select either Owner or ID, after it will create another dropdown with corresponding values, after if you select any Id or Owner see output in console, there I want number of times  occurred  either Owner or ID.